# Active Record - Find records which were created_at before today

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I want to get all records where the created_at field is less than today (a date).
Is there anything like:

```
MyTable.find_by_created_at(< 2.days.ago)
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Using [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) the standard way:

```
MyModel.where("created_at < ?", 2.days.ago)
```

Using the underlying [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) interface:

```
MyModel.where(MyModel.arel_table[:created_at].lt(2.days.ago))
```

Using some [thin layer](https://gist.github.com/1333253) over Arel:

```
MyModel.where(MyModel[:created_at] < 2.days.ago)
```

Using [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel):

```
MyModel.where { created_at < 2.days.ago }
```

Comment: thanks!. If I need all records from MyTable1 which is one to one relation with MyTable on the same condition, how to write the query? I was referring something like `MyTable1.where(MyTable[:created_at] < Time.now)`
is it possible?

Comment: Yes I have set the relation active record class.

Answer (score 15):

To get all records of `MyTable` created up until 2 days ago:

```
MyTable.where(created_at: Date.new..2.days.ago)
```

Note that you can also look for records with fields containing fields in the future in similar way, i.e. to get all records of `MyTable` with an `event_date` at least 2 days from now:

```
MyTable.where(event_date: 2.days.from_now..DateTime::Infinity.new)
```

Comment: This produces `"created_at" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 [["created_at", "4713-01-01 BC"], ["created_at", "2020-03-31 21:43:28.113759"]]`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to create a scope in `MyModel` or in `ApplicationRecord` using the [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) interface like *tokland* sugensted in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978018/active-record-find-records-which-were-created-at-before-today#answer-7978082) like so:

```
scope :col, ->(column, predication, *args) { where(arel_table[column].public_send(predication, *args)) }
```

Example usage of the scope:

```
MyModel.col(:created_at, :lt, 2.days.ago)
```

For all predications, check the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/Arel/Predications) or [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.0/activerecord/lib/arel/predications.rb). This scope doesn't break the `where` chain. This means you can also do:

```
MyModel.custom_scope1.col(:created_at, :lt, 2.days.ago).col(:updated_at, :gt, 2.days.ago).custom_scope2
```

Comment: Fantastic idea. But, `ActiveRecord::Relation` defines an instance method with the name `arel` which means you just need to pick a different name.