# How to find a Rails model created earlier than a specific time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to query for records created before a specific datetime. I can't find an example of how to do this. This is a Rails 4 application.

```
specific_time = 2.weeks.ago
Thing.where... # created earlier than specific_time
```

Comment: `Thing.where(:created_at.lt => specific_time)` - does this work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7978018/438992 and extrapolate. Seems like there are many examples, maybe Google just knows me better.

Comment: Haha, maybe. I was using DuckDuckGo instead of Google. StackOverflow didn't even tell me there was a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave mentioned, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7978082/2235594) will do.

I'll still add my 2 cents if you want to use pure `ActiveRecord`.

```
ancient_time = 100.years.ago
specific_time = 2.weeks.ago

Thing.where(created_at: ancient_time..specific_time)
# => SELECT `things`.* FROM `things` WHERE (`things`.`created_at` BETWEEN '1914-09-26 19:54:28' AND '2014-09-12 18:54:28')
```

Meh, just for the lazy :)