# Find Most Recent Rails Record In Past

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to create a Rails controller query that finds the record that is the most recent date in a column that is not in the future (which is why I can't do a simple `order` statement).  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978018/active-record-find-records-which-were-created-at-before-today), but the answer there (`MyModel.where("created_at < ?", 2.days.ago)`) throws up some errors.

I have this working properly, but if there's a week that starts in the future it selects that, not the most recent one in the past:

```
@most_recent = Plan.order("week_starting").last
```

Any thoughts as to how to do this properly in Rails?

Here's my entire `plans#index` method:

```
 def index
    @plans = Plan.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @plan = Plan.new
    @recent = Plan.order("week_starting").last  <<<THIS LINE
    @recipes = Recipe.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @monday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.monday)[0]
    @tuesday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.tuesday)[0]
    @wednesday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.wednesday)[0]
    @thursday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.thursday)[0]
    @friday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.friday)[0]
    @saturday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.saturday)[0]
    @sunday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.sunday)[0]
  end
```

Basically, I need the `plan` for the current user which has the `week_starting` value that is closest to `Date.today` yet still in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
Plan.where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).order("week_starting").last
```

Comment: This might not have been clear, but I'm looking for the most recent record that isn't in the future.  The two days thing was just an example from another question...

Comment: With your code (adapted) I think this would yield something like `Plan.where("week_starting < ?", Time.now).limit(1)`, which gives me an error saying `undefined method `week_starting' for #<Plan::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdf1c3e0348>`

Comment: Is week_starting field in plans table ?

Comment: Yes.  In the `plans` table there is a column called `week_starting` with a `date` type.  I'm using that instead of `created_at` because they won't always be the same.

Comment: Plan.where("plans.week_starting < ?", Time.now).limit(1) mention table name with column

Comment: This made a line later in the controller error...which is weird.  Also, how do I add in `where(user_id: current_user.id)1 in here?

Comment: That works perfectly so far.  How do I make it so it's only `where(user_id: current_user.id)`?

Comment: Plan.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).order("week_starting").last
also don't forgot to accept answer if it is worked for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you?

```
MyModel.where("created_at < ? ", Time.now).order('created_at DESC').first
```

Not sure why you have `week_starting` and what is that. but to get the recent record which is in the past, it shall enough